# Counterpart of ListView.setItemChecked for RecyclerView

Tags: android, api, listview, android-recyclerview

I am actually trying to convert [this library](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) from ListView to RecyclerView and I am looking for replacement of ListView.setItemChecked for RecyclerView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this [Libraray](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/) and here is [how to use](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/145010/Using-ItemSelectionSupport-from-TwoWayVi) it.